# How to implement priority queue with unordered linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue

I have the idea to implement priority queue with *unordered linkedlist*.

```
    public class UnorderedLinkedListMaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    private Node first;
    private int n;                                        //number of elements
    private class Node{
        Key key;                                          //elements
       Node next;   
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()               {return first==null;}
    public int size()                      {return n;}
    public void insert(Key key){
        Node oldfirst=first;
        first=new Node();
        first.key=key;
        first.next=oldfirst;
        n++;
    }

    public Key delMax(){
        Node node=first;
        if(node==null) {return null;}
        Key max=node.key;
        while(node.next!=null){
            Key data=node.next.key;
            if(data.compareTo(max)>0){
                max=data;
            }
            node=node.next;
        }
         first=first.next;
          n--;
        return max;
    }

    //Test Routine
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnorderedLInkedListMaxPQ<String> pq=new UnorderedLInkedListMaxPQ<String>();
        pq.insert("this");
        pq.insert("is");
        pq.insert("a");
        pq.insert("test");

        for(int j=0;j<pq.n;j++){
            StdOut.print(pq.delMax());
            StdOut.println();

        }
    }
}
```

I search the max element in the linkedlist,then return the maxest element.
But when I test,the output is `this this` which I suppose is `this test is a`.

There is something wrong with my implements?Any suggestions?

Comment: in your delMax, you are not deleting max, you are deleting first.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the way with the worst possible performance?

Comment: If you know there needs to be ordering to your data, order it.

Comment: Unrelated side note: such code is **perfect** for TDD and Unit testing. Thats a zillion times better than using a static main for "tests" that aren't tests but "print statements" only. A test **fails** when things go wrong - without the need of a human to manually figure that from some line of printed output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise,this is not the best approach to implement a priority queue. I would recommend to keep an ordered list while inserting. By doing that way,you just have to delete the first to retrieve the max and not scan through the entire linked list.

But in case you want to stick with the current approach, modify the delMax() as follows:

```
public Key delMax(){

    if(first==null) 
        return null;
    else if(n==1)
        return first.key;
    Node max=first,maxPrev=null,curr = max.next,prev = first;
    while(curr!=null){
        Key currMax = max.key;
        Key nextKey = curr.key;
        if(nextKey.compareTo(currMax)>0){
            max = curr;
            maxPrev = prev;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    if(maxPrev!=null)
        maxPrev.next=max.next;
    else
        first = max.next;
    n--;
    return max.key;
}
```

Also modify the following:

```
int k = pq.n;
for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
    StdOut.print(pq.delMax());
    StdOut.println();
}
```

This should return your desired output of `this test is a`

Comment: And what happens when you insert in an ordered list?

Comment: You might not need to iterate the full list

Comment: In algorithms analysis 'might' is very different from 'will'. Bottom-line is that for a simple singly linked-list data structure at least one of insertion or getMax operation shall result in O(N) time.

Comment: You are correct..There is no change if we are doing worst case analysis..My idea was that if you have 2 approaches , one of which will definitely take O(N) while the other might not, we should stick with the latter.